# HTML canvas keep on rendering line, even after I cleared it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am trying my hand on building a drawing app in React using HTML Canvas element.

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
///*[EN ROUGH]*/import rough from 'roughjs';

///*[EN ROUGH]*/const generator = rough.generator();

const createElement = (x1, y1, x2, y2, type) => {
  return { x1, y1, x2, y2, type };
};

const drawElement = (context, element) => {
  if (element.type === "connect") {
     context.moveTo(element.x1, element.y1);
     context.lineTo(element.x2, element.y2);
     context.stroke();
    ///*[EN ROUGH]*/const line = generator.line(element.x1, element.y1, element.x2, element.y2);
    ///*[EN ROUGH]*/context.draw(line);

  }
};

function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
  const [drawing, setDrawing] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ///*[EN ROUGH]*/const context = rough.canvas(canvas);

    //redraw all the components on re-render
    elements.forEach((element) => {
      drawElement(context, element);
    });
  });

  const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
    setDrawing(true);
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;

    const element = createElement(
      clientX,
      clientY,
      clientX,
      clientY,
      "connect"
    );
    setElements((prevState) => [...prevState, element]);
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    if (!drawing) return;
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;
    //index of the last element that was selected
    const lastElemIndex = elements.length - 1;
    const { x1, y1 } = elements[lastElemIndex];
    const updatedElement = createElement(x1, y1, clientX, clientY, "connect");

    //overwrite the previous element with the new x2, y2 coordinates of mouse move
    const elementsCopy = [...elements];
    elementsCopy[lastElemIndex] = updatedElement;
    setElements(elementsCopy);
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setDrawing(false);
  };

  return (
    <canvas
      id="canvas"
      width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
    >
      Canvas
    </canvas>
  );
};

export default App;
```

When I run this code, it produces this output when I click and drag mouse:

[image]

When I enable RoughJS to draw instead of normal canvas, the line works fine. RoughJS code can be enabled by removing comments `EN ROUGH`. I am totally lost why it's happening.

Comment: So what's the problem/issue/expected behavior exactly? I'd use the prev callback pattern on set state when you're reading previous state to update the next state.

Comment: @ggorlen I want to click, hold, and move the mouse to draw a simple line. Not the image above. And did you mean for the "elementCopy" ? I don't think I know how to do that on an array of elements.

Comment: If you're using rough JS anyway, then you're good, though, right? You used the callback version here: `setElements((prevState) => [...prevState, element]);`, so I'd use that any time you're reading state to compute the new state.

Comment: Got it makes sense and thank you. 
RoughJS is working fine. But it was a total experimental thing. I don't know what's wrong with Canvas. The exact same code works with Rough.

Comment: I bet Rough is using `beginPath()` to create new paths, but your code isn't. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `context.beginPath()` to start a new path, something Rough is probably doing on your behalf when you use it:

```js
  if (element.type === "connect") {
    context.beginPath(); // <-- Added
    // ...
```

Full example (click and drag to create a line--the white screen may make it hard to tell it's running):

```js
const { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } = React;
///*[EN ROUGH]*/import rough from 'roughjs';

///*[EN ROUGH]*/const generator = rough.generator();

const createElement = (x1, y1, x2, y2, type) => {
  return { x1, y1, x2, y2, type };
};

const drawElement = (context, element) => {
  if (element.type === "connect") {
    context.beginPath(); // <-- Added
    context.moveTo(element.x1, element.y1);
    context.lineTo(element.x2, element.y2);
    context.stroke();
    ///*[EN ROUGH]*/const line = generator.line(element.x1, element.y1, element.x2, element.y2);
    ///*[EN ROUGH]*/context.draw(line);

  }
};

function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
  const [drawing, setDrawing] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ///*[EN ROUGH]*/const context = rough.canvas(canvas);

    //redraw all the components on re-render
    elements.forEach((element) => {
      drawElement(context, element);
    });
  });

  const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
    setDrawing(true);
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;

    const element = createElement(
      clientX,
      clientY,
      clientX,
      clientY,
      "connect"
    );
    setElements((prevState) => [...prevState, element]);
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    if (!drawing) return;
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;
    //index of the last element that was selected
    const lastElemIndex = elements.length - 1;
    const { x1, y1 } = elements[lastElemIndex];
    const updatedElement = createElement(x1, y1, clientX, clientY, "connect");

    //overwrite the previous element with the new x2, y2 coordinates of mouse move
    setElements(prev => {
      const elementsCopy = [...prev];
      elementsCopy[lastElemIndex] = updatedElement;
      return elementsCopy;
    });
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setDrawing(false);
  };

  return (
    <canvas
      id="canvas"
      width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
    >
      The canvas element is unsupported by this browser
    </canvas>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Note I've used the callback version of `setElements` when reading the previous state to compute the new state.

Also, the text inside the `<canvas>` tags is fallback text that's displayed when the canvas isn't supported by the browser, so I've picked something a bit more descriptive.

Comment: you're awesome! It works.